# How to handle lens name mismatch between Darktable / exiv2 and Lensfun?

Tags: lens, darktable, lens-correction

Darktable doesn't recognise my Panasonic 12-32mm pancake on my Olympus E-M10 due to a mismatch of the exif LensType and lensfun modelname.

```
exiv2 -pt 20150824_0143.ORF | grep -ai lens
Exif.OlympusEq.LensType                      Byte        6  Lumix G Vario 12-32mm F3.5-5.6 Asph. Mega OIS
Exif.OlympusEq.LensSerialNumber              Ascii      32  05CX2294098B
Exif.OlympusEq.LensModel                     Ascii      32  LUMIX G VARIO 12-32/F3.5-5.6  
Exif.OlympusEq.LensFirmwareVersion           Long        1  4096
Exif.OlympusEq.LensProperties                Short       1  49472
Exif.OlympusEq.ConversionLens                Ascii      32  
Exif.Photo.LensSpecification                 Rational    4  12/1 32/1 35/10 56/10
Exif.Photo.LensModel                         Ascii      32  LUMIX G VARIO 12-32/F3.5-5.6
```

In lensfun database the lens is listed as `Lumix G Vario 12-32 f/3.5-5.6` which doesn't mach the `Exif.OlympusEq.LensType` which looks like the tag darktable is insisting on.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with Olympus' exif tags, exiv2's interpretation of this tag or the lensfun database or know a workaround?

Manually selecting each picture and pointing darktable to the correct lens would be really annoying...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this in the sources of Lensfun.  It will be part of the next release.  Until then, you can edit the file mil-panasonic.xml, probably in /usr/share/lensfun.  Search for "12-32" in that file, and expand the lens model name to "Lumix G Vario 12-32mm F3.5-5.6 Asph. Mega OIS".

Comment: Zuiko 60mm and 12-40mm also have wrong names that Darktable does not recognize. Changing names in `/usr/share/lensfun/mil-olympus.xml` file solves the issue. But this should not be the way of solving this issue...

Comment: @LuisA.Florit The way of solving this issue is to report it in Lensfun's bug tracker.  ;-)

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. I'm tired of making bug reports that remain ignored/untouched, specially for Fedora. I eventually gave up.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit The Lensfun bug tracker is very well maintained.

Comment: @TorstenBronger: Just looked back and saw that I didn't thank you for your help, sorry. Your workaround helped a lot and the fix was even better :) Thank you very much for your help!